# PyQt5 GUI crashes when QTreeWidget is cleared

Tags: python, pyqt5

When the # is removed from the line in the code below, why does the GUI crash when the button is clicked?

The line in the code is:

> self.treeWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.current_selection)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):

        Form.setWindowTitle("Test")
        Form.resize(600, 400)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)

        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Form)
        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(['No.', 'Colour', 'Animal'])
        #self.treeWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.current_selection)

        self.buttonWidget1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click1')
        self.buttonWidget1.clicked.connect(self.test1)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonWidget1, 1, 0)

        self.populate()

    def test1(self):
        self.treeWidget.clear()

    def current_selection(self):
        item = self.treeWidget.currentItem()
        self.no = item.text(0)
        self.colour = item.text(1)
        self.animal = item.text(2)
        print(self.no, self.colour, self.animal)

    def populate(self):
        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(['1', 'Yellow', 'Dog'])
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)

        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(['2', 'Black', 'Cat'])
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)

        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(['3', 'Green', 'Frog'])
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)

        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(['4', 'Blue', 'Snail'])
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If anyone can explain to me what is occurring, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the specific question: Why does the GUI **crash**?

This is due to new behaviour which was introduced with PyQt-5.5. To quote from the PyQt5 docs:

> In PyQt v5.5 an unhandled Python exception will result in a call to
>   Qt’s qFatal() function. By default this will call abort() and the
>   application will terminate. Note that an application installed
>   exception hook will still take precedence.

Fortunately, as the final sentence indicates, this new behaviour can be bypassed by installing an [`excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook), which will allow your program to deal with unhandled exceptions in a more graceful manner.

As a bare minimum, the old behaviour of simply printing the traceback to stdout/stderr can be restored like this:

```
def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
```

But obviously, displaying the error in some kind of message-box would be a far more preferrable way to inform the user that a problem has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if there is no selection, `currentItem()` is the first item in the tree.

When the button is clicked, `self.treeWidget.clear()` is called. All the items are removed from the tree widget, so there is no more a first item: the signal `currentItemChanged` is emitted.

If there is nothing in the tree, `self.treeWidget.currentItem()` will returns `None`. In `current_selection`, `item` is `None`, and that's why you get:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

To fix this, you can test if `item` is `None` before proceeding further:

```
def current_selection(self):
    item = self.treeWidget.currentItem()
    if item is not None:
        self.no = item.text(0)
        self.colour = item.text(1)
        self.animal = item.text(2)
    ...
```