# PyQt5 Display Console Output to QLineEdit

Tags: python, exception, console, output, pyqt5

I'm building a GUI in PyQT5 and would like to reroute my console output to a QLineEdit window so that error messages and print statements can be displayed to the user.

I've come across some solutions for this which are compatible with PyQT4, however none of them have worked with PyQT5. Namely, my program hangs and crashes when producing any exception, and rerouting console output using multithreading also causes a crash due to incompatibility with PyQt5.

I know that a special exception hook is needed for expception handling in PyQT, but I have been unable to find any examples that work specifically with PyQT5.

What solution can I implement that will let me output the console stdout to QLineEdit, and handle exceptions without crashing my application?

Thank you

Comment: The code should be identical for pyqt5, so you must be doing something wrong. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Yes the code is identical for pyqt5, but the problem is that pyqt5 has changed the way exceptions are handled, causing the application to crash whereas previously it remains open.

Comment: An [exception is being raised](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#unhandled-python-exceptions) because you are doing something wrong - that's what exceptions are for. Please [learn how to run your code in an environment that shows the python traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35610971/984421), so that you can debug the problem yourself.